# What was Satan's goal with Kevin?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-devils-advocate

I watched the movie [The Devils Advocate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil%27s_Advocate_%281997_film%29) tonight but could not understand why did Satan (played by [Al Pacino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Pacino)) choose Kevin (played by [Keanu Reeves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keanu_Reeves)) to make him a conscientious person. **Satan does not do that (*making a person good*)**. I admit in the dream he tried to make him bad, but I sensed that Satan had had a bigger plan, that is to make Kevin a good person, free from all types of *greed*. But **why did he want to do so?**

And why **Kevin and not some other random person?** Is it because he *really* is his son? Given the fact the whole thing was a dream, I believe the *son thing* was just part of the dream. So what is the actual reason then?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Satan's aim wasn't making Kevin a good person at all. His ultimate goal was creating the Anti-Christ, a supernatural being who would lead Satan's war against God. To do that he needed two of his children to conceive a child, that child would become the Anti-Christ. That's why he engineered that two of children, Kevin and Christabella (Connie Nielsen), get together. Kevin committing suicide put a monkey wrench in Satan's plans (cue Satan screaming his head off).

Then we see Kevin *wake up* back at the courtroom. Whether the preceding was a dream, or whether Satan used his powers to *reset* things is up to interpretation.

But what *is* apparent is that Satan hasn't given up on corrupting Kevin. He comes to him again, this time in the guise of a reporter who is promising to make him a star for his sudden courtroom performance. While Kevin did the right thing in court (as opposed to what he did in his past *iteration*), he is still vulnerable to his own vanity. Thus Satan's closing quote: "Vanity! Definitely my favorite sin!"

Comment: That's apparent? I never even considered that he was trying again.